# search inline backpack laravel not working,

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

### I want to inline, but for the search, nothing appears, please help, thank you

---

please help all of you to solve this problem, has anything been missed from the coding below

---

this my controller
(StoksCrudController.php)
`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\StoksRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

/**
 * Class StoksCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class StoksCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\InlineCreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    /**
     * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Stoks::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/stoks');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('stok', 'stok');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the List operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see  https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-list-entries
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {

        CRUD::column('kodeBarang');
        CRUD::column('namaBarang');
        CRUD::column('id_jenis_barang')
            ->type('select')
            ->entity('jenisbarang')
            ->model('App\Models\jenisbarang')
            ->attribute('jenis')
            ->label('Jenis Barang');
        CRUD::column('hargaJual');
        CRUD::column('discount');
        CRUD::column('stock');

        /**
         * Columns can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::column('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addColumn(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']);
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Create operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-create
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(StoksRequest::class);

        //CRUD::field('id');
        CRUD::field('kodeBarang')->label('Kode Barang');
        CRUD::field('namaBarang')->label('Nama Barang');
        CRUD::field('jenisbarang')
            ->type('relationship')
            ->placeholder('pilih Jenis Barang Anda')
            ->attribute('jenis')
            ->entity('jenisbarang')
            ->model('App\Models\jenisbarang')
            ->inline_create(true)
            ->ajax(true)
            ->label('Jenis Barang');
        CRUD::field('hargaJual')->default(0);
        CRUD::field('discount')->default(0);



        /**
         * Fields can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::field('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addField(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']));
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Update operation is loaded.
     *
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-update
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }
}
```

`
this my models (stoks.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stoks extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    protected $connection='mysql';
    protected $table = 'stok';
    // protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    // protected $fillable = [];
    // protected $hidden = [];
    // protected $dates = [];

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | FUNCTIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | RELATIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    public function jenisbarang()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Jenisbarang','id_jenis_barang','id');
    }

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SCOPES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | ACCESSORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | MUTATORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
}
```

this display does not appear search:
[image]

this display on inspection:
[image]

thaks..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the the **FetchOperation** trait to your **StocksCrudController** like this:

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\FetchOperation;
```

This will register the route needed that you are missing now: `/stoks/fetch/jenisbarang`